# IntelliJ external libraries?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I have added json-simple-1.1.jar to my project dependency through my modules. I am planning on sending this project to another person and I want them to be able to run the (command line) program, but it uses json-simple which looks like it is stored in the "external libraries" folder next to my project folder. My question is if theres is any way I can send the project with no installation of json-simple on their end, or will it work fine on other computers?

Comment: Better to include the library in the project I guess.

Comment: then what steps will they need to take in order to run the program (which will be done via a jar file from the terminal)? aka will it recognize the import if its right in the project folder?

Comment: Do you want the person to just run the program? Or open it in IntelliJ? Ah, you said you just want them to run it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually it is best to build everything into one .jar file; that is easiest to run.

[Here is some info on how to do that in IntelliJ.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206181699-Include-external-lib-jars-in-an-artifact-jar-)